# how to construct a matrix with given dimensions?

Tags: linear-algebra

Give an example (if possible) of a matrix all of whose entries are $0$ and $1$, whose left nullspace has dimension $3$, and whose column space has dimension $2$.

I started by finding the rank of the matrix (if it exist) to be $2$ since the column space has dimension $2$ and since the left null space has dimension $3$, that means the matrix should have $5$ rows since $(m-r)$, or $5-2=3$.

Then this is where I always get stuck, how can I figure out if such a matrix is possible and how can I construct one?

Would this matrix satisfy the question?
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: That matrix has $0$ nullspace. You need $5$ columns, as you stated. A correct example can be given by adding three columns to the matrix you have.

Comment: @EthanAlwaise what do you mean the matrix has $0$ nullspace? The dimension of the nullspace is $n-r$. I meant it should have $5$ rows not columns

Comment: It looks like the matrix you contracted indeed has the required properties: there are two linearly independent columns - so column space has dimension 2. Now just by setting the equation $yA = 0$ you find that the left null space is given by $(0, 0, a, b, c)\,~ a,b,c,\in \mathbb{R}$, so it is three dimensional.